# Unity Player caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, windows-10

I have a **Unity Build (player)** which is working fine on my PC but producing error(crash) on my client PC. The client has shared the log (Crash log) which is related to access Violation.

```
> Unity Player [version: Unity 5.6.2f1_a2913c821e27]

VB_Player_005.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module VB_Player_005.exe at 0033:205c16c7.

Error occurred at 2019-01-07_124838.
D:\DB\07_Mark\03_Medien\Player\01_3D_Rocket\VB\VB_Player_005.exe, run by KJ.
22% memory in use.
8073 MB physical memory [6280 MB free].
11145 MB paging file [7712 MB free].
134217728 MB user address space [134213247 MB free].
Read from location 0000000e caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI:    0x00005853  RSI: 0x00001003  RAX:   0x00000000
RBX:    0x0017eb80  RCX: 0x0000000e  RDX:   0x00000000
RIP:    0x205c16c7  RBP: 0x00000001  SegCs: 0x00000033
EFlags: 0x00010293  RSP: 0x0017e950  SegSs: 0x0000002b
R8:    0x00000010  R9: 0x00000001  R10:   0x20d67f88
R11:    0x00000000  R12: 0x00000010  R13:   0x00000000
R14:    0x05e17b00  R15: 0x0017eae0

Bytes at CS:EIP:
0f b7 31 33 ff 48 8d 59 02 44 8d 7f 08 eb 07 0f 

Stack:
0x0017e950: 06300031 00000000 40bca088 00007ff8 1.0........@....
0x0017e960: 00000000 00000000 0017ea48 00000000 ........H.......
0x0017e970: 0017eae0 00000000 05e17b00 00000000 .........{......
0x0017e980: 062cbaf8 00000000 062a1ab8 00000000 ..,.......*.....
0x0017e990: 00005853 00000000 00001003 00000000 SX..............
0x0017e9a0: 0017ea39 00000000 2052c664 00007ff7 9.......d.R ....
0x0017e9b0: 0000000e 00000000 062a1ab8 00000000 ..........*.....
0x0017e9c0: 0017eb80 00000000 0017ea48 00000000 ........H.......
0x0017e9d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017e9e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017e9f0: 0017ea08 00000000 3df0ca21 00007ff8 ........!..=....
0x0017ea00: 0630cd10 00000000 0628a6b0 00000000 ..0.......(.....
0x0017ea10: 062fd580 00000000 061e1a10 00000000 ../.............
0x0017ea20: 022b8060 00000000 00000024 00000000 `.+.....$.......
0x0017ea30: 3df00000 00007ff8 00000024 00000000 ...=....$.......
0x0017ea40: 00000042 00000000 00000000 00000000 B...............
0x0017ea50: 063052c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 .R0.............
0x0017ea60: 00000001 00000000 00000005 00000000 ................
0x0017ea70: 05e17b00 00000000 036f40d8 00000000 .{.......@o.....
0x0017ea80: 0017ee78 00000000 036f4060 00000000 x.......`@o.....
0x0017ea90: 0017eef0 00000000 2052c7ca 00007ff7 ..........R ....
0x0017eaa0: 00000000 00000000 20d68020 00007ff7 ........ .. ....
0x0017eab0: 062c7950 00000000 00000001 00000000 Py,.............
0x0017eac0: 00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001 ................
0x0017ead0: 80000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017eae0: 00000000 00000000 3dde2690 00007ff8 .........&.=....
0x0017eaf0: 00000000 00000000 00633e28 00000000 ........(>c.....
0x0017eb00: 00633da0 00000000 00000000 00000000 .=c.............
0x0017eb10: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017eb20: 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017eb30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017eb40: 00000000 00000000 f1cb0000 00007fff ................
0x0017eb50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017eb60: 00000001 00000007 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017eb70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017eb80: 0056004e 00440049 00410049 00470020 N.V.I.D.I.A. .G.
0x0017eb90: 00460065 0072006f 00650063 00390020 e.F.o.r.c.e. .9.
0x0017eba0: 00300034 0058004d 00000000 00000000 4.0.M.X.........
0x0017ebb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ebc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ebd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ebe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ebf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ec80: 000010de 0000134d 138e1043 000000a2 ....M...C.......
0x0017ec90: 7e3e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..>~............
0x0017eca0: fc431000 00000000 0000bc49 00000000 ..C.....I.......
0x0017ecb0: 0056004e 00440049 00410049 00470020 N.V.I.D.I.A. .G.
0x0017ecc0: 00460065 0072006f 00650063 00390020 e.F.o.r.c.e. .9.
0x0017ecd0: 00300034 0058004d 00000000 00000000 4.0.M.X.........
0x0017ece0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ecf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ed90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017eda0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017edb0: 000010de 0000134d 138e1043 000000a2 ....M...C.......
0x0017edc0: 7e3e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..>~............
0x0017edd0: fc431000 00000000 0000bc49 00000000 ..C.....I.......
0x0017ede0: 00000008 00000000 1fea3a7b 00007ff7 ........{:......
0x0017edf0: 036f4060 00000000 036f4060 00000000 `@o.....`@o.....
0x0017ee00: 00000008 00000000 036f40d8 00000000 .........@o.....
0x0017ee10: 0017f010 00000000 00000400 00007ff8 ................
0x0017ee20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ee30: 00000000 00007ff7 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ee40: 00000000 00000000 00633da0 00000000 .........=c.....
0x0017ee50: 00633da0 00000000 00000000 00000000 .=c.............
0x0017ee60: 05e17328 00000000 00633da0 00000000 (s.......=c.....
0x0017ee70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ee80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ee90: 00000000 00000000 00000042 00007ff8 ........B.......
0x0017eea0: 022c20b0 00000000 0000001a 00000000 . ,.............
0x0017eeb0: 00460065 0072006f 0000001a 00000000 e.F.o.r.........
0x0017eec0: 00000042 0058004d 00000000 00000000 B...M.X.........
0x0017eed0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017eee0: 0056004e 00440049 00410049 00470020 N.V.I.D.I.A. .G.
0x0017eef0: 00460065 0072006f 00650063 00390020 e.F.o.r.c.e. .9.
0x0017ef00: 00300034 0058004d 00000000 00000000 4.0.M.X.........
0x0017ef10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ef90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017efa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017efb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017efc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017efd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017efe0: 000010de 0000134d 138e1043 000000a2 ....M...C.......
0x0017eff0: 7e3e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ..>~............
0x0017f000: fc431000 00000000 0000bc49 00000000 ..C.....I.......
0x0017f010: 4449564e 47204149 726f4665 39206563 NVIDIA GeForce 9
0x0017f020: 584d3034 00000000 00000000 00000000 40MX............
0x0017f030: 00000000 00000000 3db25b90 00007ff8 .........[.=....
0x0017f040: 0017f0d1 00000000 3db25a38 00007ff8 ........8Z.=....
0x0017f050: 3db258e0 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 .X.=............
0x0017f060: 000000c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f070: 022ab230 00000000 00000004 00000000 0.*.............
0x0017f080: 00000007 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f090: 030e89e0 00000000 2056d369 00007ff7 ........i.V ....
0x0017f0a0: 20f44340 00007ff7 20ff2d50 00007ff7 @C. ....P-. ....
0x0017f0b0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f0c0: 030e89e0 00000000 2056d79d 00007ff7 ..........V ....
0x0017f0d0: 00000010 00000000 030c7050 00000000 ........Pp......
0x0017f0e0: 00000001 00000000 00633da0 00000000 .........=c.....
0x0017f0f0: 00000010 00000000 1fc87241 00007ff7 ........Ar......
0x0017f100: 00000010 00000000 210498a0 00007ff7 ...........!....
0x0017f110: 0017f208 00000000 3db2593c 00007ff8 ........<Y.=....
0x0017f120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f130: 00000000 00000000 203cbd60 00007ff7 ........`.< ....
0x0017f140: 022ab230 00000000 00000004 00007ff8 0.*.............
0x0017f150: 00000007 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f160: 00000000 00000000 3db4bd5b 00007ff8 ........[..=....
0x0017f170: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f180: 0017f208 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f190: 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 ................
0x0017f1a0: 210498a0 00007ff7 1fc87325 00007ff7 ...!....%s......
0x0017f1b0: 00000010 00000000 00000270 00000000 ........p.......
0x0017f1c0: 21049a00 00007ff7 00000001 00000000 ...!............
0x0017f1d0: 210470a0 00007ff7 203cc184 00007ff7 .p.!......< ....
0x0017f1e0: 00000017 00000000 00000270 00000000 ........p.......
0x0017f1f0: 00000010 00000000 00000018 00000000 ................
0x0017f200: 00000000 00000000 20ff2d50 00007ff7 ........P-. ....
0x0017f210: 061b0188 00000000 3db4c053 00007ff8 ........S..=....
0x0017f220: 20ff2d48 00007ff7 20c96820 00007ff7 H-. .... h. ....
0x0017f230: 3dd5ac48 00007ff8 3db4c539 00007ff8 H..=....9..=....
0x0017f240: 05e17328 00000000 00000000 00000000 (s..............
0x0017f250: 00000001 00000000 203cbd60 00007ff7 ........`.< ....
0x0017f260: 00000000 00000000 00000270 00000000 ........p.......
0x0017f270: 00000010 00000000 00000017 00000000 ................
0x0017f280: 00000000 00000000 20c6c26c 00007ff7 ........l.. ....
0x0017f290: 00000282 00007ff7 20ff2d50 00007ff7 ........P-. ....
0x0017f2a0: 00000001 00000000 203cc0d2 00007ff7 ..........< ....
0x0017f2b0: 030e87c0 00000000 00000002 00000000 ................
0x0017f2c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f2d0: 20c6c26c 00007ff7 00000282 00007ff7 l.. ............
0x0017f2e0: 00000000 00000000 1fea6504 00007ff7 .........e......
0x0017f2f0: 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017f300: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017f310: 00000282 00000000 000001c0 00000000 ................
0x0017f320: 0056004e 00440049 00410049 00470020 N.V.I.D.I.A. .G.
0x0017f330: 00460065 0072006f 00650063 00390020 e.F.o.r.c.e. .9.
0x0017f340: 00300034 0058004d 00000000 00000000 4.0.M.X.........
0x0017f350: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f360: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f370: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f380: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f390: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f3a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f3b0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f3c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f3d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f3e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f3f0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f400: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f410: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f420: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f430: 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017f440: 00000000 00000000 030e87c0 00000000 ................
0x0017f450: 00000002 00000000 1fea9b0b 00007ff7 ................
0x0017f460: 036f4060 00000000 00000005 00000000 `@o.............
0x0017f470: 43000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ...C............
0x0017f480: 20c6c26c 00007ff7 203cbd60 00007ff7 l.. ....`.< ....
0x0017f490: 030e87c0 00000000 1feed86e 00007ff7 ........n.......
0x0017f4a0: 00000000 00000000 00000017 00000000 ................
0x0017f4b0: 00000000 00000000 20c6c26c 00007ff7 ........l.. ....
0x0017f4c0: 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017f4d0: 00000000 00000000 1fefcaa6 00007ff7 ................
0x0017f4e0: 038e6c60 00000000 00000000 00000000 `l..............
0x0017f4f0: 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f500: 00800000 00000000 00000065 00007ff7 ........e.......
0x0017f510: 030e7d10 00000000 00000001 00000000 .}..............
0x0017f520: 00000000 00000000 1fe718ec 00007ff7 ................
0x0017f530: 00000000 00000000 1fbb0000 00007ff7 ................
0x0017f540: 00000000 00000000 038ded30 00000000 ........0.......
0x0017f550: 00000000 00000000 1fe7403c 00007ff7 ........<@......
0x0017f560: 20fdfe01 00007ff7 0017f5b9 00000000 ... ............
0x0017f570: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017f580: 20f680e0 00007ff7 205bd81e 00007ff7 ... ......[ ....
0x0017f590: 00000000 00000000 20d1a718 00007ff7 ........... ....
0x0017f5a0: 00000000 00000000 63726f66 66672d65 ........force-gf
0x0017f5b0: 6f6a2d78 00007362 0000000e 00000000 x-jobs..........
0x0017f5c0: 00000042 00007ff7 0017f628 00000000 B.......(.......
0x0017f5d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f5e0: 00000000 00000000 20051dea 00007ff7 ........... ....
0x0017f5f0: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f600: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f610: 0017f6c0 00000000 203dbf4b 00007ff7 ........K.= ....
0x0017f620: 20d1a718 00007ff7 00000000 00000000 ... ............
0x0017f630: 00000000 00000000 0229b9e0 00000000 ..........).....
0x0017f640: 00000000 00000000 203d9bee 00007ff7 ..........= ....
0x0017f650: 0000776f 00000000 0000000a 00000000 ow..............
0x0017f660: 00000042 00000000 00000000 00000000 B...............
0x0017f670: 00000050 0000002b 1fc197c0 00007ff7 P...+...........
0x0017f680: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0017f690: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f6a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f6b0: 00000000 00000000 0229b9e0 00000000 ..........).....
0x0017f6c0: 0017f7d0 00000000 1fc1e97a 00007ff7 ........z.......
0x0017f6d0: 00cf0000 00000000 00000140 00000000 ........@.......
0x0017f6e0: 000000f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f6f0: 00000000 00000000 1fc87268 00007ff7 ........hr......
0x0017f700: 20c68370 00007ff7 20c6bac0 00007ff7 p.. ....... ....
0x0017f710: 00000000 00000000 ffebffff 00000000 ................
0x0017f720: 0017f7ac 00000000 20c37568 00007ff7 ........hu. ....
0x0017f730: 02180310 00000000 2056d79d 00007ff7 ..........V ....
0x0017f740: 00000000 00000000 00637465 00646567 ........etc.ged.
0x0017f750: 20f68f10 00007ff7 00000003 00000000 ... ............
0x0017f760: 00000042 00000000 0229b990 00000000 B.........).....
0x0017f770: 0229b9e0 00000000 0229b9e0 00000000 ..).......).....
0x0017f780: 00000000 00000000 021803e0 00000000 ................
0x0017f790: 021803e0 00000000 022afab0 00000000 ..........*.....
0x0017f7a0: 00000067 00000000 00000408 00000016 g...............
0x0017f7b0: 00000067 00000000 00000042 00007ff8 g.......B.......
0x0017f7c0: 02180450 00000000 021803e0 00000000 P...............
0x0017f7d0: 02297690 00000000 00000070 00000000 .v).....p.......
0x0017f7e0: 0017f850 00000000 00000070 00000000 P.......p.......
0x0017f7f0: 00000042 000013bb 022afc70 00000000 B.......p.*.....
0x0017f800: 00000062 00000000 205c6416 00007ff7 b........d\ ....
0x0017f810: 00000062 00000000 00000042 00000000 b.......B.......
0x0017f820: 022afb90 00000000 0000006a 00000000 ..*.....j.......
0x0017f830: 00000004 00000000 0000006a 00000000 ........j.......
0x0017f840: 00000042 00000000 02297890 00000000 B........x).....
0x0017f850: 00000071 00000000 205bde1a 00007ff7 q.........[ ....
0x0017f860: 00000071 00000000 00000042 00007ff7 q.......B.......
0x0017f870: 0000000f 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f880: 00000000 00000000 205bdebe 00007ff7 ..........[ ....
0x0017f890: 00000022 00000000 022afa40 00000000 ".......@.*.....
0x0017f8a0: 0000006b 00000000 00000000 00000000 k...............
0x0017f8b0: 0000006b 00000000 00000042 00007ff7 k.......B.......
0x0017f8c0: 20f68f10 00007ff7 009a1f20 00000000 ... .... .......
0x0017f8d0: 009a0840 00000000 20c6ba01 00007ff7 @.......... ....
0x0017f8e0: 00000000 00000000 205d019a 00007ff7 ..........] ....
0x0017f8f0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f900: 00000000 00000000 1fbb0000 00007ff7 ................
0x0017f910: 00000000 00000000 205c1dcc 00007ff7 ..........\ ....
0x0017f920: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f930: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f940: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f950: 00000068 00000000 005f2a4a 00000000 h.......J*_.....
0x0017f960: 005f2a2a 00000000 005f2966 00000000 **_.....f)_.....
0x0017f970: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f980: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000401 ................
0x0017f990: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f9a0: 00000000 00000000 00010001 00000000 ................
0x0017f9b0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f9c0: 00000000 00000000 40c23034 00007ff8 ........40.@....
0x0017f9d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f9e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017f9f0: 00000000 00000000 42ea3691 00007ff8 .........6.B....
0x0017fa00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fa10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fa20: 00000000 00000000 3f97bb60 00007ff8 ........`..?....
0x0017fa30: 0017da50 00000000 0017da50 00000000 P.......P.......
0x0017fa40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fa50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fa60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fa70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fa80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fa90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017faa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fab0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fac0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fad0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fae0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017faf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fb90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fba0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fbb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fbc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fbd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fbe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fbf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fc90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fca0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fcb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fcc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fcd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fce0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fcf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fd90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fda0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fdb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fdc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fdd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fde0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fdf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fe90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fea0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017feb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fec0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fed0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fef0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ff90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ffa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ffb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ffc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ffd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017ffe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0017fff0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................


== [end of error.log] ==
```

I google and didn't found any comprehensive solution while I have experience this kind of error before in different unity builds and mostly found the reason of this error are

**1. Low disk space
 2. Heavy project
 3. 32 or 64 bit architecture problem**

But in current situation I don't think any above error is valid as it is a small project which is running on low end PC pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google of "Read from location 0000000e caused an access violation." showed a few people having this issue, and uninstalling or configuring citrix seemed to solve it.

> "*While I am not OP, I had the same problem. I couldn't find any running Citrix processes (not 100% sure though, the application spawns dozens of processes), but still got the crash with the same 0000000e Access Violation.
>   I could fix the issue without uninstalling Citrix by disabling the "Citrix Virtual Bus Enumerator" in the Device Manager.*" - m3adow - [Forum Link](https://forums.unknownworlds.com/discussion/155160/discovered-reason-for-game-crashing-when-launching-access-violation)

Comment: You mean  citrix application creating the problem? I should uninstall it for resolution of the crash

Comment: For some people citrix was the culprit, try disabling it before uninstalling it unless you're not using it